# SQL JOIN on multiple possibilities

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a weird query I have to make.  I have two tables that have a multiple-to-multiple relationship, so a bridge table is in the middle.  The bridge table is populated right now by:

```
select
    P.RTPropertyUniqueIdentifier
    , P.ParcelID
    , M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number
    , M.FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID
    , M.Property_Type
    , M.Property_Address
    , P.AddUnitNum
    , 0 as multiple_flag
    into PP_MLS_BRIDGE
FROM MLS M
join PROPERTY_PARAMETERS P on
    replace(replace(M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number, ' ', ''), '.', '') = P.ParcelID;
```

Here's my issue.

The join fields are `Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number` and `ParcelID`.  There's over 180Million records in one table and 20Million records in the other.  My problem is that there's more than one way those two can be matched:

1. `Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number` = `ParcelID`
2. `replace(replace(M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number, ' ', ''), '.', '')` = `ParcelID`
3. `replace(replace(replace(M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number, ' ', ''), '.', ''), '_', '')` = `ParcelID`

and there maybe more in the future.

The problem is if I perform a `join on OR` situation, it Cartesian the answers.  I need a one-for-one join on any ONE of the conditions.  How do I restructure this so it'll scan once and if there's a join on any of the conditions it's a join?

Thanks.
.

Comment: Are you looking for a technology agnostic solution? I've solved something similar issues using ROW_NUMBER using SQL Server; Partition your results by Primary Key then pick the first result by RowNumber. For 20 Million results you might want a different approach though.

Comment: It's not clear - can the table validly be joined on, say 2 of these representations? Or is this a data cleansing exercise? I suggest you add a column (either calculated or loaded in batch) that works out the correct join value, then just join on that column (another advantage is that you can index it)

Comment: I think such a situation is not maintainable. 
I would add a column called `ParcelId` to the `MLS` table, do my best to convert all existing `Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number` into a valid ParcelID, and for the future check the matching at insertion time.

Comment: I can see the column thing, but I would still have a problem matching the fields.  The fact that it could be a match based upon 1 of 3 possible means, will still be there.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm trying to bridge the two tables together with as much matching as possible.  The results of the match go into the bridge table.  The problem I have here is the join condition on three possible assoications.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 ways I see to go about this are:

First you need to determine the order in which it attempts joins. Then you need to determine the logic for which joined is used. Finally, apply that logic in a case statement on the join.

I'm assuming none of the joins provided can be used 100% of the time and should be identical in the resulting join.

```
    JOIN PROPERTY_PARAMETERS P ON
    ParcelID = CASE
        WHEN Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number IS NOT NULL THEN Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number 
        WHEN TRY_CAST(replace(replace(M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number, ' ', ''), '.', '') AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN TRY_CAST(replace(replace(M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number, ' ', ''), '.', '') AS INT) = ParcelID
        WHEN TRY_CAST(replace(replace(replace(M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number, ' ', ''), '.', ''), '_', '') AS INT) IS NOT NULL THEN TRY_CAST(replace(replace(replace(M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number, ' ', ''), '.', ''), '_', '') AS INT) = ParcelID
        END
```

The other option would be to join the table 3 times, once for each join available. You could then isnull(isnull(resulta,resultb),resultc).

Regardless, these are both less than ideal solutions that will not scale well with a table this large. The ideal solution would be cleaning the data to provide a single column identifier that you could use.

Comment: ok.  I tried what you suggested..I got thrown a out of memory exception error.

Comment: You can try running it against the server, but query is taking all your local memory and could impact the server depending on resources. Is cleaning the data to provide a single column identifier a possibility? If not, you can try testing it limiting the result set.

Comment: ok.  I've been trying to setup a column but I don't know what to put in there.  how do I know which conversion needs to be put in there when I don't know what the join is going need? (three possibilities)?  Thanks